# Retrieving and combining multiple dictionary entries

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have file with pairs of values going like this:

```
123    456
84665   88
90  2339
2624    5371
6118    6774
```

I also have a dictionary where several keys contain more than one value, represented by a list. Example:

```
{123: ['A1B1C1', '2X3P4T5O'], 456: ['C5H5J8F3', 'D3K21F9', 'F1N5NA3']}
```

Now, what I want to do is, for each entry in the pairs line (e.g: `123` and `456`), obtain this:

```
A1B1C1 C5H5J8F3
A1B1C1 D3K21F9
A1B1C1 F1N5NA3
2X3P4T5O C5H5J8F
2X3P4T5O D3K21F9
2X3P4T5O F1N5NA3
```

That is, combining every single value from the 123 key, with every single value from the 456 key.
Some keys have only one value, but other keys have as much as 6.

I've been working with this:

```
for line in infile:
        lread += 1
        column = line.strip().split('\t')

        value1 = data.__getitem__(column[0])
        value2 = data.__getitem__(column[1])
        total1 = len(value1)
        total2 = len(value2)
        num1 = 0
        num2 = 0
```

And then tried using while loops, for loops, with various combinations of range(len()), but couldn't do what I wanted.
I'm pretty sure it goes that way, but since I'm new to programming I seem to can't get it right.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two nested for-loops should do what you want:

```
for line in infile:
    columns = line.strip().split()
    for x in data[columns[0]]:
        for y in data[columns[1]]:
            print x, y
```

Depending on what you want to do, you can also use a list comprehension with a nested for-loop or `itertools.product()`.

Comment: That is amazing! I was using just one for loop and I knew it wouldn't get me anywhere. But I'm not sure if I understand what you just did, even though it works.
Could you 'translate' it? Much appreciated!

Comment: @EdwardCoelho: It's basically what the code says: "for each `x` in `data[columns[0]]`, iterate over each `y` in `data[columns[1]]`."

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do this:

```
(a, b) = [data[x] for x in column]
values = [(x, y) for x in a for y in b]
```

Values will then be a list of the pairs you want:

```
[('A1B1C1', 'C5H5J8F3'), ('A1B1C1', 'D3K21F9'), ('A1B1C1', 'F1N5NA3'), ('2X3P4T5O', 'C5H5J8F3'), ('2X3P4T5O', 'D3K21F9'), ('2X3P4T5O', 'F1N5NA3')]
```

Comment: Very, very good. Works great! Made a great deal of research on list tools but haven't came across list comprehensions.
Thanks for the heads up!